# st_network_blend does not include all points

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf, sfnetwork

I would like to do a bending between the network `Riv` and the points `df` with the function

```
library(sf)
net <- as_sfnetwork(Riv) |>
  st_network_blend(df)
```

Nevertheless in this exemple, two points are removed in the output (38, 120).
I am looking for a way to bend all the points in the given network.

```
Riv <- structure(list(id = 1, geometry = structure(list(structure(c(279507.756152689, 
279496.389160699, 279487.579741907, 279477.065274316, 279471.665953121, 
279467.971680724, 279462.288184729, 279457.173038333, 279450.352843139, 
279448.079444741, 279430.176432356, 279416.820216768, 279397.212155585, 
279392.665358789, 279355.154285221, 279354.301760822, 279338.956321635, 
279324.747581647, 279315.938162855, 279302.581947266, 279294.625052873, 
279284.394760082, 279266.207572898, 279253.419706909, 279246.599511714, 
279236.369218923, 279223.297178134, 126843.360320325, 126845.349543923, 
126847.054592722, 126849.896340719, 126851.601389518, 126851.601389518, 
126851.601389518, 126849.896340719, 126849.32799112, 126849.04381632, 
126855.011487115, 126860.41080831, 126873.482849099, 126880.587219093, 
126900.763629875, 126901.616154274, 126906.44712587, 126907.29965027, 
126905.026251872, 126901.616154274, 126899.342755876, 126895.64848348, 
126883.42896709, 126885.986540288, 126886.554889887, 126891.954211083, 
126900.763629875), dim = c(27L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
"sfg"))), n_empty = 0L, crs = structure(list(input = "BD72 / Belgian Lambert 72", 
    wkt = "PROJCRS[\"BD72 / Belgian Lambert 72\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"BD72\",\n        DATUM[\"Reseau National Belge 1972\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"International 1924\",6378388,297,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4313]],\n    CONVERSION[\"Belgian Lambert 72\",\n        METHOD[\"Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of false origin\",90,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8821]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of false origin\",4.36748666666667,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8822]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 1st standard parallel\",51.1666672333333,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8823]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 2nd standard parallel\",49.8333339,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8824]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Easting at false origin\",150000.013,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8826]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Northing at false origin\",5400088.438,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8827]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"easting (X)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"northing (Y)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Engineering survey, topographic mapping.\"],\n        AREA[\"Belgium - onshore.\"],\n        BBOX[49.5,2.5,51.51,6.4]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",31370]]"), class = "crs"), class = c("sfc_LINESTRING", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 279223.297178134, 
ymin = 126843.360320325, xmax = 279507.756152689, ymax = 126907.29965027
), class = "bbox"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("sf", 
"data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(id = NA_integer_), class = "factor", levels = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity")))
```

```
df <- structure(list(geometry = structure(list(structure(c(279461.047725, 
126850.828982), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279471.850771, 
126850.434784), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279461.600959, 
126853.524052), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279477.622451, 
126848.998012), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279487.333524, 
126846.386556), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279432.618277, 
126855.779098), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279462.114815, 
126853.349535), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279459.709928, 
126852.784385), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279462.634304, 
126853.646268), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279464.104559, 
126852.34611), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279460.525507, 
126852.057152), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279461.943233, 
126851.922813), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279455.790451, 
126849.496129), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279463.029965, 
126850.70146), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279462.662644, 
126850.174628), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279459.928063, 
126851.945586), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279462.606883, 
126854.746546), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279461.926269, 
126852.314836), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279453.401994, 
126849.007272), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279453.651751, 
126849.738384), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279459.229805, 
126851.573168), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279461.604216, 
126851.122261), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279462.632447, 
126852.856737), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279462.65262, 
126852.349694), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279462.472094, 
126853.200606), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279452.138754, 
126849.115283), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279463.172444, 
126850.328626), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279459.342917, 
126849.738244), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279445.008342, 
126849.725012), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279463.831275, 
126853.398651), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279462.819294, 
126850.956011), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279460.830336, 
126852.600472), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279485.833601, 
126847.749308), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279463.610849, 
126852.607739), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279453.117239, 
126850.110347), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279463.658051, 
126850.149101), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279462.012276, 
126850.075728), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279461.826927, 
126853.016637), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279478.986862, 
126849.792752), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279480.666583, 
126850.375603), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279446.183482, 
126850.504251), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279457.877851, 
126850.270125), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279462.236599, 
126851.00315), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279489.494214, 
126847.537526), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279466.444841, 
126851.942667), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279480.001968, 
126849.053918), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279458.473767, 
126850.450916), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279438.335202, 
126854.041641), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279477.597359, 
126850.204792), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279484.343244, 
126846.666658), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279485.105268, 
126848.814882), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279485.806615, 
126845.929235), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279483.430773, 
126850.499909), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279482.140866, 
126848.498698), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279466.317559, 
126851.666972), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279473.207856, 
126849.138954), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279479.147495, 
126850.340441), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279469.370398, 
126850.397727), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279472.215248, 
126852.368758), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279472.328427, 
126851.398592), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279453.41179, 
126849.337293), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279485.784208, 
126847.335485), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279486.14318, 
126846.832537), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279473.852034, 
126849.102676), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279472.95162, 
126852.124049), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279478.35171, 
126850.383573), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279474.256748, 
126848.668214), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279471.517068, 
126850.504505), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279473.560632, 
126850.307387), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279472.902263, 
126851.093206), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279474.101945, 
126852.159925), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279474.342943, 
126851.530142), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279473.241454, 
126850.224655), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279472.918423, 
126851.834796), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279476.281047, 
126847.843752), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279473.554013, 
126852.11457), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279437.364954, 
126850.537163), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279475.09422, 
126848.049405), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279467.368493, 
126851.7603), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279476.118381, 
126852.599234), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279474.030119, 
126851.484283), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279472.132073, 
126849.615477), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279470.762018, 
126851.014004), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279476.710636, 
126850.620486), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279430.398141, 
126855.077191), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279452.905725, 
126849.333537), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279468.953731, 
126851.750077), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279474.458842, 
126851.624103), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279473.83588, 
126850.584063), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279479.60999, 
126849.773955), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279471.570311, 
126851.141144), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279479.08071, 
126851.19211), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279475.491207, 
126851.875552), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279462.376662, 
126851.974461), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279464.449914, 
126850.990314), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279476.076152, 
126850.747734), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279474.100852, 
126850.734305), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279471.084995, 
126854.263564), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279469.6689, 
126851.41826), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279478.634543, 
126850.698427), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279478.132384, 
126849.441586), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279467.935292, 
126850.860078), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279464.972597, 
126852.055098), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279465.727472, 
126852.596526), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279466.819062, 
126850.211128), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279477.379878, 
126852.672366), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279455.619918, 
126849.508401), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279461.582409, 
126850.160118), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279478.665487, 
126849.384254), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279478.357877, 
126851.055353), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279468.674094, 
126850.41286), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279469.435244, 
126852.776082), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279475.598089, 
126849.419795), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279470.731167, 
126851.555642), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279459.830752, 
126851.520698), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279460.39306, 
126851.010528), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279486.186951, 
126845.877251), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279460.816828, 
126852.562426), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279482.648044, 
126848.326928), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279461.833796, 
126853.736982), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279480.17933, 
126850.945485), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279466.752634, 
126853.207904), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279470.166005, 
126852.904565), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279454.818492, 
126849.688792), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279460.255726, 
126853.538839), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279489.355847, 
126846.681466), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279487.706023, 
126846.023335), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279456.581215, 
126850.643081), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279462.892312, 
126851.437007), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279460.332868, 
126850.187095), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279462.814175, 
126853.932974), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279466.178942, 
126850.579383), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279483.468619, 
126847.662682), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279458.089547, 
126851.130423), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279461.667497, 
126849.783768), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279484.103686, 
126847.929406), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279469.168623, 
126854.072839), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279459.792793, 
126851.975168), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279482.675889, 
126847.03776), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279465.177138, 
126850.52086), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279471.732504, 
126851.978363), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279472.962478, 
126849.66225), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279464.488014, 
126852.960836), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279465.083755, 
126851.037086), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279483.934794, 
126848.066812), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279484.671745, 
126846.168451), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279481.423421, 
126849.762186), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279484.26992, 
126849.201587), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279482.392713, 
126847.815808), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279484.433132, 
126848.781681), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279464.451565, 
126851.480798), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279484.382978, 
126847.365641), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279467.360089, 
126852.300603), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279479.61541, 
126849.09658), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279466.14978, 
126852.559351), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279484.886854, 
126847.868377), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279484.119702, 
126847.161682), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279470.625807, 
126852.693822), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279445.460584, 
126850.649931), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279466.599221, 
126851.342311), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279483.260098, 
126846.444127), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279465.39646, 
126851.578243), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279461.446417, 
126851.685286), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279467.060466, 
126851.315361), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279481.666825, 
126847.166348), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279465.997014, 
126851.952645), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279464.850045, 
126852.084361), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279479.812024, 
126849.716072), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279446.528814, 
126849.413107), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279483.387615, 
126848.617533), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279467.410871, 
126852.647228), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279463.045599, 
126851.092913), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279467.192462, 
126850.610957), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279482.857071, 
126846.589774), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279467.362675, 
126853.431139), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279482.048481, 
126846.644867), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279483.374352, 
126849.372888), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279474.598772, 
126851.767638), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279483.756836, 
126847.842287), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279482.567311, 
126849.302691), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279478.641653, 
126850.870422), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279482.584101, 
126848.925143), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279485.124647, 
126849.512707), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279468.769474, 
126850.634403), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279465.55247, 
126851.777254), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279467.715807, 
126852.224001), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279484.93287, 
126849.113865), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279480.346107, 
126850.045142), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279484.791499, 
126845.99656), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279480.127622, 
126849.258311), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279467.322434, 
126853.021458), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279486.804416, 
126848.35358), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279479.544454, 
126850.434595), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279470.121986, 
126853.850284), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279482.601255, 
126848.578303), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279481.566547, 
126847.214042), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279467.009571, 
126851.380604), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279479.828672, 
126848.274003), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279482.380271, 
126850.493798), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279483.59185, 
126846.991595), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279482.02476, 
126847.51028), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279487.78452, 
126846.968042), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279457.870443, 
126849.984086), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279461.16455, 
126849.963184), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279488.307303, 
126845.539744), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279485.386716, 
126848.442623), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279459.80964, 
126851.036509), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279489.139433, 
126845.779799), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279434.000227, 
126853.71917), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279488.398219, 
126845.904312), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279463.260793, 
126852.27146), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279460.798162, 
126851.031585), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279457.770687, 
126849.800649), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279459.121238, 
126850.63793), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279463.172401, 
126852.817819), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279489.218588, 
126846.103556), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279475.093668, 
126850.922541), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279485.527982, 
126847.860657), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279487.131018, 
126848.017635), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279483.507056, 
126849.00883), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279472.48728, 
126852.42986), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279479.08314, 
126848.543496), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279479.947657, 
126848.028482), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279479.29483, 
126848.473483), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279481.523654, 
126848.576679), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279476.953854, 
126850.595786), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279478.51345, 
126849.139782), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279480.668225, 
126848.242369), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279480.932874, 
126847.654764), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279478.383989, 
126848.108634), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279481.73884, 
126850.835788), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279478.251508, 
126852.58589), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279480.334514, 
126848.239168), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279480.275468, 
126852.22225), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279472.230346, 
126852.358287), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279481.167625, 
126850.781138), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279481.09048, 
126847.210934), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279480.834739, 
126851.757584), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279480.266324, 
126850.307201), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279480.548103, 
126847.687017), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279480.688103, 
126849.937926), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279476.961619, 
126848.248541), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279477.729186, 
126851.805566), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279475.402826, 
126850.56343), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279473.75986, 
126851.276479), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279481.653266, 
126851.727288), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279463.946761, 
126853.503227), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279479.591367, 
126852.104519), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279477.468634, 
126851.690289), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279469.722892, 
126851.433212), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279470.403465, 
126849.918062), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279480.70051, 
126851.457466), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279478.415813, 
126848.985753), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279479.954161, 
126852.142618), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279481.108743, 
126847.296647), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(279481.306497, 
126851.107172), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 279430.398141, 
ymin = 126845.539744, xmax = 279489.494214, ymax = 126855.779098
), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "EPSG:31370", 
    wkt = "PROJCRS[\"BD72 / Belgian Lambert 72\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"BD72\",\n        DATUM[\"Reseau National Belge 1972\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"International 1924\",6378388,297,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4313]],\n    CONVERSION[\"Belgian Lambert 72\",\n        METHOD[\"Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of false origin\",90,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8821]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of false origin\",4.36748666666667,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8822]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 1st standard parallel\",51.1666672333333,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8823]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 2nd standard parallel\",49.8333339,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8824]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Easting at false origin\",150000.013,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8826]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Northing at false origin\",5400088.438,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8827]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"easting (X)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"northing (Y)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Engineering survey, topographic mapping.\"],\n        AREA[\"Belgium - onshore.\"],\n        BBOX[49.5,2.5,51.51,6.4]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",31370]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L), 
    N = 1:256), row.names = c(NA, -256L), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(N = NA_integer_), levels = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), class = c("sf", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The difference between the df and the output

```
x <- st_as_sf(net, "nodes")
setdiff(df$N, x$N)
#>[1]  38 120
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to answer my question by using a loop with `while`. For that, first I create a function for extraction of the bent points, with the functions `st_network_blend()` and `st_as_sf()` from the `sf` package.

```
distfn <- function(df){
  net0 <- as_sfnetwork(Riv) |>
    st_network_blend(df)  
  distances0e <- net0 %>% #group_by(Substation) %>% #'net' works better than 'new_network'  
    activate("nodes") %>% 
    st_as_sf() %>% 
    filter(!row_number() %in% c(1,2))
}
```

After, I created a function which will filter any non-bent points, gather the output with first bending operation and repeat the process if necessary.

```
Distloop <- function(df){
  dist  <- distfn(df)
  Diff <- setdiff(df$N, dist$N)
  x <- as.numeric(length(Diff))
  if(as.numeric(length(Diff)) == 0){
    dist
  } else {
    while(x != 0){
      dfbis <- df %>% filter(N == Diff)
      distb <- distfn(dfbis)
      dist <- dist %>% rbind(distb)
      Diff = setdiff(df$N, dist$N)
      x <- as.numeric(length(Diff))
    };
    dist;
  };
}
```

`Distloop(df)` provide the correct amount of observation